# How can I add a library and include file to a CMake project without hard coding /usr/local/[lib|include]/subdir?

Tags: c++, cmake

I am working on a cmake project that requires another library "foo" to have been locally installed (i.e. by running `make ; sudo make install` in its source dir).

"foo" in this case happens to be another cmake project that installs itself as a header and .a library file into `${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}/foo/foo.h` and `${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/foo/foo.a`. Unfortunately, `foo.h` includes its own `bar.h` as `#include "bar.h"`, not `#include "foo/bar.h"`. So any project using the foo library needs to add the `foo` subdirectory to its search paths.

On my machine I can build my executable by the following CMakeLists.txt:

```
find_library(FOO_LIBRARIES NAMES foo PATH /usr/local/lib/foo)
add_executable(my_exe main.cc)
target_link_libraries(my_exe ${FOO_LIBRARIES})
target_include_directories(my_exe /usr/local/include/foo)
```

However, this approach requires hard-coding `/usr/local/lib` and `/usr/local/include`, which seems brittle and wrong. What's a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Command [find_library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_library.html) has a special parameter `PATH_SUFFIXES` which denotes a suffix to be appended to the search path:

```
find_library(FOO_LIBRARIES NAMES foo PATH_SUFFIXES "foo")
```

Similar parameter exists for command [find_path](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_path.html), which is used for find include directories.

```
# Usual include directory, which contains 'foo/foo.h'
find_path(FOO_INCLUDE_DIR "foo/foo.h")
# Specific include directory, which contains (directly) 'bar.h'
# This specific directory is usually suffixed with 'foo/'.
find_path(BAR_INCLUDE_DIR "bar.h" PATH_SUFFIXES "foo")

target_include_directories(my_exe ${FOO_INCLUDE_DIR} ${BAR_INCLUDE_DIR} )
```

---

Using `find_library` and `find_path` is useful for possible work with *locally-installed* libraries. E.g., if `foo` library will be installed with custom installation prefix `/home/me/foo-install`, then it will be sufficient to add that prefix into [CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.html) variable.

Answer (score 0):

Use CMake mechanics to [export/import targets](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/importing-exporting/index.html).

Briefly speaking, your `foo` project ought to produce CMake exported target (and corresponding configs). So, your project just uses `find_package(foo...)` to *import* it. Having properly configured [build requirements](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html) for `foo`, in your project you gonna use just `target_link_libraries()` and forget about paths and other compiler/preprocessor/linker options maybe required to link w/ `foo`.

Comment: Yes ideally it would. Perhaps I'll go for a pull request